# Deleting string from @

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *string=@"test1@sdk.com";
```

Now I want to delete all the characters of the string from @ which result in "test1".
Please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

So your code should be like below.

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sdk.com" withString:@""];
```

**EDITED:**

Use `componentsSeparatedByString` method,

```
 NSArray* myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
```

Now your array contain exactly two component,

```
NSMutableString* myStringBefore = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

if you still want @ at the end of your string ..

```
[myStringBefore appenString:@"@"];
```

Comment: this string is just an example of what I have to do it might be testabc@gmail.com.So the solution needs to be general

Comment: I found a solution int range=[string rangeOfString:@"@"].location;
 NSLog(@"%d",range);
 NSLog(@"%@",[string substringToIndex:range]);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substringToIndex](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
string = [ string substringToIndex:5 ] ;
// If @ location is subject to change, then first find it's location index and
// pass it.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"test1@sdk.com"];
 NSArray* arr = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
[string1 deleteCharactersInRange: [string1 rangeOfString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[arr objectAtIndex:1]]]];
```

Comment: Why not simply `[[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] objectAtIndex:0]`? No need for a mutable string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int range=[string rangeOfString:@"@"].location; 
NSLog(@"%d",range); 
NSLog(@"%@",[string substringToIndex:range]);
```